# Clipboard util made in WinAPI

Tags: c++, winapi

I've made a small click-to-copy clipboard util in WinAPI that doesn't steal focus, stays on top of all windows, can be dragged and simulates <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> keystrokes if needed.

[image: Clipboard util]

What can be improved and are there any pitfalls I am overseeing? I am aware of checking if the call to Clipboard succeeded and that I should avoid this one:

```
(WPARAM)GetStockObject(DEFAULT_GUI_FONT)
```

Here is the source code:

```
// A tool to quickly copy the strings to clipboard
#pragma comment(linker,"\"/manifestdependency:type='win32' \
name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' \
processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
#include <windows.h>
#include "resource.h"
#include <string>

static wchar_t szWindowClass[] = L"myclass2.0";
static wchar_t szTitle[] = L"Ron's utils";
HINSTANCE hInst;
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

//=========================== global constants ===========================
// positions and dimensions
const int formydelta = 95;
const int formwidth = 775;
const int formheight = 55;
const int buttony = 15;
const int buttonx = 15;
const int buttonxdelta = 85;
BOOL pastedirectly = false;

// hard coded strings
const std::string sotexthelp = "Please take [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [the help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help). Welcome to SO.";
const std::string sotextbooks = "Sounds like you could benefit from reading one of [these C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).";
//========================================================================

// copy to clipboard function
void copytoclipboard(const std::string& s){
    HGLOBAL hMem = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_MOVEABLE, s.size() + 1);
    memcpy((LPWSTR)GlobalLock(hMem), s.c_str(), s.size() + 1);
    GlobalUnlock(hMem);
    OpenClipboard(0);
    EmptyClipboard();
    if (!SetClipboardData(CF_TEXT, hMem)){
        GlobalFree(hMem);
    }
    CloseClipboard();
}
// paste from clipboard function:
void pastefromclipboard(){
    if (pastedirectly) {
        INPUT myinput[4];
        SecureZeroMemory(myinput, sizeof(myinput));
        myinput[0].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        myinput[0].ki.wVk = VK_LCONTROL;
        myinput[1].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        myinput[1].ki.wVk = 'V';
        myinput[2].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        myinput[2].ki.wVk = 'V';
        myinput[2].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
        myinput[3].type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        myinput[3].ki.wVk = VK_LCONTROL;
        myinput[3].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
        SendInput(4, myinput, sizeof(INPUT));
    }
}
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow){
    WNDCLASSEX wcex;
    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW | CS_DROPSHADOW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICON1));
    wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW);
    wcex.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wcex.lpszClassName = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICON1));

    if (!RegisterClassEx(&wcex)){
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Call to RegisterClassEx failed!", L"cppexamples.com", NULL);
        return 1;
    }

    hInst = hInstance;
    HWND hWnd = CreateWindowEx(
        WS_EX_NOACTIVATE | WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW | WS_EX_TOPMOST,
        szWindowClass,
        szTitle,
        WS_POPUP | WS_BORDER | WS_VISIBLE,
        ((GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN) - formwidth) / 2), (GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN) - formydelta),
        formwidth, // width
        formheight, // height
        NULL,
        NULL,
        hInstance,
        NULL
        );

    if (!hWnd){
        MessageBox(NULL, L"Call to CreateWindow failed!", L"cppexamples.com", NULL);
        return 1;
    }
    SetWindowPos(hWnd, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE);
    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0)){
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
    return (int)msg.wParam;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;

    switch (message){
    case WM_CREATE:
    {
        // button 1
        HWND hwndButton = CreateWindow(
            L"BUTTON",
            L"Email",
            WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
            buttonx, // x position 
            buttony, // y position 
            75, // width
            24, // height
            hWnd,
            (HMENU)101, // ID
            hInst,
            NULL);
        SendMessage(hwndButton, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)GetStockObject(DEFAULT_GUI_FONT), 0);

        // code for other buttons omitted
        // button exit
        HWND hwndButton110 = CreateWindow(
            L"BUTTON",
            L"Exit",
            WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
            formwidth - 90,
            buttony,
            75,
            24,
            hWnd,
            (HMENU)110,
            hInst,
            NULL);
        SendMessage(hwndButton110, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)GetStockObject(DEFAULT_GUI_FONT), 0);
        //checkbox
        HWND hwndCheckBox = CreateWindowEx(0, L"BUTTON", L"Paste directly",
            BS_AUTOCHECKBOX | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
            formwidth - 180, buttony + 3,
            90, 20,
            hWnd,
            (HMENU)111,
            hInst,
            0);
        SendMessage(hwndCheckBox, WM_SETFONT, (WPARAM)GetStockObject(DEFAULT_GUI_FONT), 0);
    }
    break;
    case WM_COMMAND: // process commands
        switch (LOWORD(wParam)) {
        case 101:
        {
            copytoclipboard("sample string 1");
            pastefromclipboard();
        }
        break;
        // code for other buttons omitted
        case 110:
        {
            OpenClipboard(0);
            EmptyClipboard();
            PostQuitMessage(0);
        }
        break;
        case 111: // checkbox
        {
            pastedirectly = IsDlgButtonChecked(hWnd, 111);
        }
        break;
        }
        break;
    case WM_NCHITTEST: {
        LRESULT hit = DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        if (hit == HTCLIENT) hit = HTCAPTION;
        return hit;
    }
    break;
    case WM_PAINT:
        hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code hardly has any error handling. You never check return values of essential functions, such as `GlobalLock`, `OpenClipboard` and never call `GetLastError` to figure out what caused failure.

There are magic numbers scattered everywhere from UI dimensions to command ids.

Fancy problem: this code is not exception-safe. If `string` constructor at call to `copytoclipboard` fails (out of memory for example) the exception will raise out of `WndProc` callback causing undefined behavior since calling C code is not aware of C++ exceptions. If your application supposed to handle low memory scenarios then you can call `copytoclipboard` inside of `try..catch` block and manually deal with thrown exceptions. Or (as alternative) you can mark `WndProc` and other callbacks with `noexcept` specifier so compiler won't let sudden exceptions to get into C code and will call `terminate`.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback. I will implement the error checking / handling. How should I ago about replacing the C++ `std::string`?

Comment: Maybe use the `LPCWSTR` pointer instead? How likely is it the std::string ctor will raise an exception?

Comment: @Ron If your application supposed to handle low memory scenarios then you can call `copytoclipboard` inside of `try..catch` block and manually deal with thrown exceptions. Or (as alternative) you can mark `WndProc` and other callbacks with `noexcept` specifier so compiler won't let sudden exceptions to get into C code and will call `terminate`. Using `LPCWSTR` would be just dropping handy C++ class. It could work when you are passing come constant though.

Comment: Awesome info. Would appreciate if you could incorporate the comment into an answer.

Comment: Also worth mentioning this is for my personal needs, not production.

Answer (score 0):

I will be speaking as I am not the author and I need to maintain this program.

- There is no alternative to direct pasting implemented; it only emulates <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> right now and the program won't work with checkbox not enabled.
- The identificators of UI elements are hard to keep an eye on. The better way of dealing with it is having `enum` with human readable labels to which you assign the integers if you need to. Handles could be named better as well.
- And of course there are so many better ways of writing the GUI other than hard-coding all coordinates inside the code. Visual Studio is definitely the way to go if you want to write something maintainable in WinAPI GUI.

Comment: @Ron well this is code review and in this specific case it only matters for someone who maintains the program. If you take a second look years after writing something you will be puzzled if the code is not self-documenting.